# how to create subfolder in document directory in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to create another folder in document directory and then .I want to pass some file in that folder which is create in document directory then i want to make this folder as zip file

please help me on this how to work on this

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/yourFolderName"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```